Are anti-semetic theories allowed in answers?
This answer https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/97617/62932 contains the following rant:

All of the genealogical records that proved each tribes ancestry were stored in that temple, and were destroyed when it burned in AD 70. Those who today call themselves Jews can no longer prove any lineage back to Abraham, nor to Jacob. If asked, they will tell you that they take the word of a person who claims to be of Levite, or of Dan, or Judah, etc.

This seems like a variant of a "Fake Jews" theory (explained by ADL) which posits that some Jews lie about their ancestry.
Are answers that denigrate an ethnic or religious group allowed on this website?

This is a very important question. We can't allow harmful, blanket stereotypes that misrepresent Israel or any people group. We look at facts on this manuscript study site.  Bible study is not a cudgel for prejudices of any kind. Thank you!

Thank you for raising this question. In this particular case, the user who posted this paragraph did not consider how this statement would be received by those of modern Jewish heritage, and after discussion has voluntarily removed the claim. We don't often comment on Moderation decisions, but due to the severity of the public claim here it seems prudent to provide some response.
SE Policy on Abusive Behaviour
The Code of Conduct is the first port of call to refer to on these topics, but also contains further links to more specific policy sections, such as the Abusive behaviour policy, which has the following to say:

Dangerous speech – any form of expression (e.g. text, images, or
speech) that represents rhetoric that demonizes or denigrates a group
of people in a way that depicts them as threats so serious that
violence against them becomes acceptable or necessary; rhetoric that
increases the risk of violence being condoned or committed against a
particular group. This policy is inspired by the Dangerous Speech
Project.
Bigotry & Discrimination – the poor treatment, expressed irrational
suspicion, hatred, targeting, and/or intolerance of another person or
group of people due to their ethnicity, age, sexual orientation,
gender identity and expression, disability, or held religious beliefs.

In my personal opinion, this paragraph did not really embody any of these behaviours - it did not feature any elements of violence, intolerance, suspicion, hatred or anything like that. Rather, it was a theological claim in response to a question aboute eternal ordinances. It was certainly not a conspiracy theory by any known definition, even if there are similar theories that have been weaponised by others for specific purposes.
Though this type of instance isn't clearly covered in the CoC, the content is 'rude or abusive' in respect to the fact that it is certainly rude to suggest that any group or individual's ethnic or cultural heritage is invalid unless written on a piece of paper somewhere. When somebody has had heritage passed to them by previous generations, should we not assume faithful transmission unless there is evidence to the contrary? Assuming unfaithful transmission is a bad-faith claim, in my view. It's not dissimilar to conversations on the site around other oral transmission issues with regards to biblical history.
However, in my view the user was not intending to be rude or abusive, and did not realise it could be construed in this way, and needed some help understanding how the statement could be received. Once this was understood, they freely retracted the statement.
Comments on Moderator intervention
Please do allow time for moderators to review and intervene in issues, as we are all volunteers and check in intermittently with many flags to work through, and so it can take several hours for anybody to even realise that something requires intervention. Be assured that we prioritise high severity flags like rude/abusive content, and resolve these as quickly as possible.
Meta can be a place to make issues public and engage in a wider community conversation, but is more here for when things aren't working or a change in direction should be considered. It would have been better to allow time for normal content review and site processes to happen, and then only raise this issue to Meta if the outcome was problematic or you saw a wider issue that needed to be addressed.
If there is ever a case where you are concerned about or wish to formally object to Moderator decisions, it may also be more appropriate to use the Contact form to reach the Community Moderation team so that they can review our decisions and conduct. Especially with regards to issues with individuals on the site, we are usually unable to comment publicly on such matters.
Conclusion
No, answers that denigrate an ethnic or religious group are not allowed on this website.
However, this situation appears to have been a misunderstanding. When encountering questionable content, please Flag it for moderator attention, and if appropriate leave a friendly Comment requesting clarification or explaining in what way you find the content objectionable, in line with our Expected Behaviours:

Be nice. Whether you've come to ask questions, or to generously share
what you know, remember that we’re all here to learn, together. Be
welcoming and patient, especially with those who may not know
everything you do.

It can be tempting to jump to worst-case conclusions, and to raise accusations of malevolent intent, but this is not usually helpful. Escalating to a conflict situation can put others on the defensive and make it more difficult for them to understand your perspective or to reflect on how their content is perceived by others.
With mutual kindness a great number of issues and conflicts can be quickly and amicably resolved, as the scriptures encourage us to consider:

Leviticus 19:18
“You shall not take vengeance or bear a grudge against any of your people, but you shall love your neighbor as yourself: I am the LORD.”

Stack Exchange is all about Community content, and so we all play a huge part in site moderation and user engagement. Building a positive sense of engagement between community members can be challenging with a wide range of deeply held viewpoints, but with some earnest effort we have collectively shown that it's possible.

Why is my question edited to say things that I didn't want to say? The OP said Those who today call themselves Jews can no longer prove any lineage back to Abraham - where did OP say some Jews like my question was edited to say?

@AviAvraham it looks like it was corrected for clarity, as the theory cited is specifically about Ashkenazi Jewish heritage, rather than all Jewish groups. I'll query it, but at first glance it looks sensible enough.

@AviAvraham the goal is to edit some style so more visitors will appreciate your good message. The edit did not change the quote portion. As enraging as anti-semitism is, we want to use an objective, neutral tone in response so that readers know we are even-tempered about it. That will make our response more believable. And, this meta question succeeded, since that cited post was edited to also use a neutral tone when commenting on the history lost in AD 70. We're really glad to have you!

It is rare that I lack mod privileges for BH.SE but since I can't note above, I will state here: This SE has long made it clear that This is not a Christian site. Judaism has much to offer biblical hermeneutics for obvious reason and this ought to be remembered. Anyone who has scholarly content to share regardless of race, creed, gender, religion or anything else ought to be welcome. This was clearly a No True Scotsman Fallacy but the poster retracted that and I agree with Steve's analysis
